# Displaying "application-specific" validation errors in web UI using Thymeleaf's "fields.hasErrors"

Tags: spring-mvc, bean-validation, thymeleaf

I use Spring MVC together with Thymeleaf. I have an issue with Thymeleaf `fields.hasErrors` which is as follows:

When a **Bean Validation constraint** error is raised (such as a @NotNull constraint), the following use of `fields.hasErrors` works perfectly:

```
<span class="help-inline" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('member.email')}" th:text="#{message_form.validation.email}"></span>
```

An error message is displayed OK next to the email field.

However, when an **"application-specific" error** (as opposed to **Bean Validation constraint error**) is raised by my code (see code from controller below),

```
// FROM SPRING MVC CONTROLLER
if (!registrationService.isEmailAvailable(registrationInfo.getMember().getEmail())) {
    bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("member.email", "email already used")); // TODO i18n
}
```

The `th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('member.email')}"` **does not evaluate to true** and no error message is displayed....

The only way I have found to display those "application-specific" errors is to include the following underneath the form:

```
<div id="errors" class="alert alert-error">
    <ul th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
        <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then, it will display "*email already used*" as a list item.

Can anyone please clarify the behavior of `th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('member.email')}"` and especially tell me why it will **evaluate to false** in the case of **"application specific" errors**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution to my isue: My problem comes from an incorrect usage of the Spring API.

I should be using a `FieldError` instead of an `ObjectError`.

So changing from:

```
   //FROM SPRING MVC CONTROLLER
    if (!registrationService.isEmailAvailable(registrationInfo.getMember().getEmail())) {
        bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("member.email", "email already used"));//TODO i18n
    }
```

to

```
   //FROM SPRING MVC CONTROLLER
    if (!registrationService.isEmailAvailable(registrationInfo.getMember().getEmail())) {
        bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("registrationInfo","member.email", "email already used"));//TODO i18n
    }
```

solved the problem.